# Why does my texture looks pixelated? And How can I fix it?

Tags: texture-painting

when I apply my texture it looks like this, it also happens when I try to paint. Can someone help me?
[image]

Comment: Try to change shading from Flat to Smooth.

Comment: Also "*Why does my texture looks pixelated?*" It is too small "*And How can I fix it?*" increase its size

Comment: What resolution are you using for your texture, and what does the UV unwrap look like in relation to the image texture? Not enough pixels assigned to each part, or overall not enough pixels to allow smooth painting is what I think I see, but more screen shots woudl be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture looks like it is fine but it looks more like it is a shading problem.
In edit mode select all the faces and under the Shading/UVs click smooth.

Your texture could be pixelated because of image compression JPG are bad PNG are good

[image]